# Crop an image with given angle

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I have the center, the angle of inclination (direction) and the measures of the sides of a sub-image that I want to crop from another image, for example:

[image: original image]

to:

[image: final image]

I managed to put it with the right inclination using:

```
    Mat img;
    Point center;
    float angle;
    Mat rotation = getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0);
    warpAffine(img, img, rotation, img.size());
```

But I dont know how to cut that area with the given sides... How can I do it?

Comment: Do you have the corner pixel coordinates?

Comment: No, I have to calculate them?

Comment: It would be one possibility

Comment: If you can rotate the image, after that you just need one of the corners position (for instance, bottom-right corner) and the width and height of the image you want to crop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rotate the image, after that you just need one of the corners position (for instance, bottom-right corner) and the width and height of the image you want to crop.

With that said, you can set a ROI (region of interest) and crop with

```
cv::Rect RegionOfInterest(top_left_x, top_left_y, rectangle_width, rectangle_height);
cv::Mat outputImage;

outputImage = originalImage(RegionOfInterest).clone();
```

where `top_left_x` and `top_left_y` are your top left corner coordinates, and `rectangle_width` and `rectangle_height` are the width and height of the rectangle you are interested in extract.